# Why does zero UIView's CALayer.speed stops UIAlertController's buttons from working?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uialertcontroller

I have a custom activity indicator that is a full screen `UIView` with `CABasicTransformation` for rotation added to its **layer** property. When I set `layer.speed = 0` in my custom `hideActivityIndicator()` method and then present an alert, I can not interact with its buttons or whatever, while say before I present an alert I can select a cell in table view in the same controller after I set `layer.speed = 0`. To be clear that is the only line of code that produces the effect. If I comment it out alert works beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

By default, animations cause UI elements to stop accepting "user interaction" (taps.)

My guess is that when you set the animation speed to 0, the animation is always running, never finishes, and user interaction is disabled.

You might be able to set the `allowUserInteraction` flag on your buttons, but the `allowUserInteraction` is a property of UIView.AnimationOptions, so I'm not sure how you'd do that.

You might try using a UIView animation on the view's transform property rather than a CABasicAnimation on the layer. Then you could use the `allowUserInteraction` property when setting up the animation.

(Note that under the covers UIView animations actually create CAAnimations, and setting the layer's animation speed to 0 will still freeze the animation.)

Comment: Thanks mate! The thing is I ended up just by removing all "state preserving" machinery from my custom activity indicator: various layer.beginTime layer.timeOffset and layer.speed - thus ended up by constantly having animation layer on the activity indicator view. And it causes no issues now...mystery...